# how to get ExpandableListView child text

Tags: android, json, expandablelistview

i am using expandable listview with json array. i have get  [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269261/how-to-make-expandablelistview-with-json-array/18271181#18271181)

my question is how to get child title as string. I need child data while click childlist.

```
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


      GlobalData.childheader=ListChildXXXXXXXXX.get(
                     Listparent.get(groupPosition)).get(
                             childPosition);

}
```

It not executed. please help

Comment: It said the method get(int) in the type Arraylist<Arraylist<Childthebu> is not applicable for the argument parent. please help me

Comment: Replace Listparent to ListChildTerbaru.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269261/how-to-make-expandablelistview-with-json-array/18271181#18271181. check and pls help. i need it

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is ListChildXXXXXXXXX? Is that JSON? Also what's Listparent? Please post more code so we can understand what's going on before onChildClickListener.

What you did seems OK to me, here's an example of mine onChildClickListener:

```
private ArrayList<Page> headerPagesArray;
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Page>> childPagesArray;

... SOME CODE TO MAKE THIS ALL WORK ...

lvListMenu.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Page childPage = childPagesArray.get(headerPagesArray.get(groupPosition).getPageId()).get(childPosition);

            GoToPageEvent event = new GoToPageEvent("GoToPage", childPage);
            EventBus.getDefault().postSticky(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In this example headerPagesArray is ArrayList of  objects, and childPagesArray is ArrayList of ArrayList> where string is page id of the parent page.

EDIT:

OK after explaining what's what, this should work:

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {


  GlobalData.childheader=ListChildXXXXXXXXX.get(
                 ListChildTerbaru.get(groupPosition)).get(
                         childPosition);

}
```

--- UPDATE 2 ---

Ah now after careful reading i see what's the problem...

You're trying to call .get() with a ChildTerbaru object (or Parent object earlier) while it should be called with simple int.

So your call must be something like:

```
GlobalData.childheader=ListChildXXXXXXXXX.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
```

After this everything should work taken that GlobalData.childheader is of type ChildTerbaru

Comment: hello Bojan Kopanja, ArrayList<ChildTerbaru> ListChildTerbaru;
 ArrayList<Parent> Listparent;
 ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildTerbaru>> ListChildXXXXXXXXX;

Comment: i referred this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269261/how-to-make-expandablelistview-with-json-array/18271181#18271181. if u found answer please help

Comment: i got same error sir.. The method get(int) in the type ArrayList<ArrayList<ChildTerbaru>> is not applicable for the arguments (ChildTerbaru)

Comment: Sorry i misread the problem earlier, what i wrote now should work properly.