# How to create custom expandable list view with JSON Record

Tags: java, android, json, expandablelistview

I want to add custom expandable list view. I'm getting products record in json format and every product have multiple variants. I want to add expandable list view of each product. When user click on list it will expand and show all the variants of it's product. Is this possible to add expandable list view dynamically with json record?
My json is:

```
{ 
   "productss":[  
      {  
         "product_id":"1",
         "product_name":"Product 1",
         "product_image":"product_images\/1.jpg",
         "product_created_date":"2017-07-11 19:14:30",
         "variants":[  
            {  
               "variants_id":"1",
               "variants_name":"Small",
               "variants_price":"20.0000",
               "variants_cost":"15.0000",
               "variants_quantity":"50"
            },
            {  
               "variants_id":"2",
               "variants_name":"Medium",
               "variants_price":"25.0000",
               "variants_cost":"20.0000",
               "variants_quantity":"20"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "product_id":"2",
         "product_name":"Product 2",
         "product_image":"product_images\/2.jpg",
         "product_sizes":"3",
         "product_created_date":"2017-07-11 19:14:29",
         "variants":[  
            {  
               "variants_id":"3",
               "variants_name":"Small",
               "variants_price":"20.0000",
               "variants_cost":"15.0000",
               "variants_quantity":"50"
            },
            {  
               "variants_id":"4",
               "variants_name":"Medium",
               "variants_price":"25.0000",
               "variants_cost":"20.0000",
               "variants_quantity":"20"
            },
            {  
               "variants_id":"5",
               "variants_name":"Large",
               "variants_price":"30.0000",
               "variants_cost":"25.0000",
               "variants_quantity":"25"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: you could use [expandable-recycler-view](https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view)

Comment: can i use expandable list view?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269261/how-to-make-expandablelistview-with-json-array